# Save desktop layout in Delphi Community Edition

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I am wondering if it is possible to save a Desktop Layout while using Delphi 10.3 Community Edition.

I am doing this process, but I am not finding the Save Desktop Layout Option.

View --> Desktops --> Save Desktop Layout

[image: Save Desktop layout missing]

**EDIT**

Answer by Uwe Raabe

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you find the *desktop select box* in the title bar? To the left is a button opening a popup menu with the save option.

Comment: And if it's not appears there, just right click on the IDE then from the menu check _Desktop_

Comment: Omg, can't believe I was not founding it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SoonSantos You're not the first - and probably not the last - not finding that thing. A good sign that the design is flawed tbh.

Answer (score 1):

i think it's new bug

**workaround:**

use ide insight with 'save des..',and select the command from the popup list.

Comment: Thank you for your time. @Uwe Raabe answer solved the issue.